# Насколько корректно?

Tags: грамотная-речь

"Лица, занимающие посты на должностях госслужбы" — корректно?

Answer (score 1):

Некорректно. Пост и должность - синонимы. Налицо смысловая тавтология. Необходимо убрать из предложения одно из этих слов.

Словарь синонимов:
Должность, занятие, место, пост, служба, звание; синекура. Исправлять, занимать должность. Состоять на службе. Быть не у дел. Ваканции как раз открыты. Гриб. Ср. Занятие.
См. занятие, обязанность Л исправлять должность, слагать с себя должность